# Bresenham line algorithm drawing off lines

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics, bresenham

I am attempting to implement the Bresenham line algorithm in a c++ paint program.

It draws fine when x is increasing but it seems to do a weird algorithm

```
int dx = old_x - x;
int dy = old_y - y;

if (dx >= 0){
    step_x = 1;
} else {
    step_x = -1;
    dx = fabs(dx);
}

if (dy >= 0){
    step_y = 1;
} else {
    step_y = -1;
    dy = fabs(dy);
}

int dx2 = dx * 2;
int dy2 = dy * 2;

if (dx > dy){
    err =  dy2 - dx;

    for (int i = 0; i <= dx; i++){
        currTool.draw(old_x, old_y);
        if (err >= 0){
            err -= dx2;
            old_y += step_y;
        }
        err += dy2;
        old_x += step_y;
    }
} else {
    err = dx2 - dy;

    for (int i = 0; i <= dy; i++){
        currTool.draw(old_x, old_y);
        if (err >= 0){
            err -= dy2;
            old_x += step_x;
        }
        err += dx2;
        old_y += step_y;
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple things, such as flipping the x, y I have rewritten the code following multiple examples and have had no luck.

This is the link to the site I converted

http://www.falloutsoftware.com/tutorials/dd/dd4.htm

Here is a picture of what is happening to my program

[image]

Comment: [**This**](http://i.imgur.com/mPZaTpr.jpg) may be helpful . I basically drew the line based of slopes. Basically you get the slope of both points , and then divide it by a lot then draw those single points by incrementing `rise/run` . I have never actually tested and converted this to code , but i think this should work.

Comment: `old_x += step_y` ?

Comment: (Using `fabs` to negate an integer is also a bit unusual.)

Comment: Doesn't fabs just return the abs? What's weird about that? And the old_x += step_y actually reversed the issue lol

Comment: I think he means `old_x += step_y` (in your `dx > dy` case) should be `old_x += step_x`.

Comment: Yup, what I do the the lines where x decreases it's fine and now becomes stagnant when X increases

Comment: Looks like a case for using debugger and stepping through the situation of pixels going to wrong places.